# What would cause a UNION to take an excessive amount of time?

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization, union

I have a statement that looks like:

```
QUERY A
UNION
QUERY B
ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

Query A and Query B each take a nominal amount of time to run, but when I put them in the UNION, it take 7-9 seconds which is unacceptable. In this case Query A returns 6 rows, Query B returns 7. So confusing...

I have absolutely no idea what would cause this, help would be much appreciated!

Here is an anonymized version of the script (I did not write this, so don't hate):

```
SELECT 
    'XXX' l_t, 
    s.p, 
    srst.c_b, 
    srd.a_d_f, 
    s.s_c, 
    sf.c_s, 
    srst.p_f, 
    s.s_r_i, 
    s.s_i, 
    s.s_d, 
    srd.m_s_d_l s_d, 
    srd.m_e_d_l e_d, 
    CASE WHEN (srs.s_s_t IS NOT NULL AND srs.s_s_t <> srs.s_e_t) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 's_f', 
    CASE WHEN (srs.c_s_t IS NOT NULL AND srs.c_s_t <> srs.c_e_t) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'c_f', 
    r.r_i 
FROM 
    t_s_r_d srd 
    INNER JOIN t_s s WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON s.s_i = srd.s_i 
    INNER JOIN i_s_r(12345) r 
    ON r.r_i = srd.r_i 
    INNER JOIN i_s_s_f() sf 
    ON (sf.s_i = srd.s_i)
    INNER JOIN t_s_r_s srst WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (srst.s_i = srd.s_i AND srst.r_i = srd.r_i ) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_s_r_s srs WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON (srs.s_i = srd.s_i AND srs.r_i = srd.r_i) 
WHERE 
    srst.d_f = 0  
    AND ((srd.m_s_d_l >= someval AND srd.m_s_d_l < someotherval) 
        OR 
        (srd.m_s_d_l <= someval AND srd.m_e_d_l > someotherval)) 
    AND r.o_f = 0 
    AND r.i_f = 0 
    AND r.v_f = 1 
    AND r.g_i = 180 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t_c_r cdr WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE cdr.r_i = r.r_i)

UNION 

SELECT 
    'XXX' l_t, 
    s.p, 
    srst.c_b, 
    srd.a_d_f, 
    s.s_c, 
    sf.c_s, 
    srst.p_f, 
    s.s_r_i, 
    s.s_i, 
    s.s_d, 
    srd.m_s_d_l s_d, 
    srd.m_e_d_l e_d, 
    CASE WHEN (srs.s_s_t IS NOT NULL AND srs.s_s_t <> srs.s_e_t) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 's_f', 
    CASE WHEN (srs.c_s_t IS NOT NULL AND srs.c_s_t <> srs.c_e_t) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'c_f', 
    c.c_i 
FROM 
    (t_s_r_d srd 
    INNER JOIN t_s s WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON s.s_i = srd.s_i 
    INNER JOIN i_s_s_f() sf 
        ON (sf.s_i = srd.s_i)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_s_r_s srs WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON (srs.s_i = srd.s_i AND srs.r_i = srd.r_i) 
    INNER JOIN t_s_r_s srst WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON (srst.s_i = srd.s_i AND srst.r_i = srd.r_i)), 
    i_s_c(12345) c 
WHERE 
    srst.d_f = 0  
    AND ((srd.m_s_d_l >= someval AND srd.m_s_d_l < someotherval) 
        OR 
        (srd.m_s_d_l <= someval AND srd.m_e_d_l > someotherval)) 
    AND c.o_f = 0 
    AND c.i_f = 0 
    AND c.v_f = 1 
    AND c.g_i = 180 
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t_c_r cr WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE cr.r_i = srd.r_i and 
        cr.c_i = c.c_i)
ORDER BY s_d
```

Comment: Is the column that backs SomeColumn in A and B identical datatype? What happens if ORDER BY clause is commented out? Is SomeColumn a real or computed column? Can you provide actual query rather than pseudo?

Comment: They are, and the order by has no effect :(

Comment: Leaving the order by out of the query it is still slow? If so, remove it from the pseudo code as irrelevant to the case in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the old style ansii style joins in conjunction with the newer style explicit joins that were causing the lengthy return. Quite interesting, if anyone could provide a reason why that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Because `UNION` removes duplicates it has to sort the whole data set first...try to use `UNION ALL` instead....it is much faster since it doesn't need to remove the dups

Comment: The result set is 13 rows, thats why I am confused. I tried UNION ALL, no effect :(

Comment: when you run each query separate, do you add the ORDER BY, if it is slow in that case it means you don't have an index that the sort operation can use

Comment: Nope, first thing I did was check the execution plan. All expected indexes are present. I even rebuilt every index in the database but it only dropped the time from 10 seconds to 8 :(

Comment: Could it be a mismatch in column types somewhere, such that it has to convert one column and in so doing breaks in an index?

Comment: Doesnt look like it, its weird. Because if I import the data by hand into a new empty db, it works fine :/